# If if statement inside method returns false, loop until it returns true

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, setter, mutators

I can't seem to figure this out.

I want it to do so if the user either types something that doesn't equal to 12 characters or else, it loops until what the user types matches the requirements of the if statement that returns true.

setter:

```
//boolean returning method for validation
public boolean setSSN(String ssN) {
    
    if (ssN.length() != 12) {

        return false;
    }
    if(Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(1)) &&
       Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(2)) && ssN.charAt(3) == '-' &&
       Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(4)) && Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(5)) &&
       Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(6)) && ssN.charAt(7) == '-' &&
       Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(8)) && Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(9)) &&
       Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(10)) && Character.isDigit(ssN.charAt(11))) {
        
        ssNumber = ssN;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error message") ;
        return false;
    }
    }
```

main:

```
    System.out.println("What is your social security number using this format XXX-XXX-XXXX: "); 
    
    do {
    System.out.print("SSN: ");
    String input1 = in.nextLine();
        employee1.setSSN(input1);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(employee1.toString());
        
        System.out.println();
    } while(!employee1.setSSN(true));
```

Let me know if there's something missing. I just started programming 2 two terms after programming 1 and I am a bit rusted with everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling your method twice.  The use an endless loop which you will break out of when successful.

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("What is your social security number using this format XXX-XXX-XXXX: "); 
    System.out.print("SSN: ");
    String input1 = in.nextLine();
    if (employee1.setSSN(input1))   // returns true if valid
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(employee1.toString());
        break;
    }
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The validation logic should be moved from `setSSN` setter because validating a value and setting this value to an instance field are *two* responsibilities.

Thus, the setter should look as simple as:

```java
// Employee class
public void setSSN(String ssn) {
    this.ssNumber = ssn;
}
```

2. [Regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) should be used to validate string patterns, in this case method [`String::matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) can be applied instead of multiple checking `Character.isDigit`

The method to validate SSN in the format `###-###-####` where `#` means a digit may look then as:

```java
public static boolean isSSNValid(String ssn) {
    return ssn.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
}
```

This *single* method may be modified if needed with extra validations (e.g. to check  SSN control sum) or if SSN format changes.

3. Reading of a valid value may be encapsulated in another function accepting a scanner/reader and returning a valid string:

```java
public static String readValidSSN(Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("What is your social security number using this format XXX-XXX-XXXX?");
    String inputSSN;
    System.out.print("SSN: ");
    while (!isSSNValid(inputSSN = in.nextLine())) {
        System.out.println("Input SSN has invalid format, please try again");
        System.out.print("SSN: ");
    }
    return inputSSN;
}
```

Then main method would be simplified like this:

```java
// ...
employee.setSSN(readValidSSN(in));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(employee); // method toString is invoked automatically
System.out.println();
```